# Query about Visa for a E13 TV-L position (19.9 hours of work per week)

Tags: germany, india, visa

I am student from India and finished my master's this year. I secured a PhD position at Göttingen university in mathematics. In my offer letter it is written that I will be employed from 1.10.2018 to 30.09.2021 as a research assistant at the mathematical institute of the George-August-Universität Göttingen. I will be hired part-time (19,9 h/week) and paid according to E13 TV-L (minimum 1758,68 € per month).

[Here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/84913/what-visa-is-required-for-a-tv-l-phd-position-in-germany) someone wrote that, with a TV-L position, getting a student visa is not only problematic, but also something that can't be fixed later. But it looks like I have a 50% position. In Germany, people are are considered a student from the perspective of social security (health insurance, pension, unemployment insurance), if work is less than 20 hours per week (in my case it is 19,9, as per contract). So I could be considered a student as well. I don't understand which Visa I should go for. In India, the available long term Visas are [these](https://india.diplo.de/in-en/vertretungen/generalkonsulat3/-/2001158). I guess it should go for Student, Employment or Guest Scientist Visa. But I don't understand which one. This seems to be a very complicated affair. What should I do?

Comment: Why don't you call the embassy and ask for advice? The administration of Göttingen University might also be able to advise. You will be hardly be their first Indian employee/PhD student.

Comment: The student status at your university is completely independent of your visa. One thing to keep in mind is that if you opt for the student visa and you ever decide to quit you PhD, you have to leave the country immediately (not the next day, but you can't stay the full duration). So the advice still stands: As soon as you earn any money, opt for the employment visa.

Comment: I have no idea about the visa issues, but I'd reckon a TV-L position is _not_ a student assistant position, but a full-fledged working position. So, while my intuition says "work permit visa", I'd recommend you to check with the ambassy and/or international office of your university.

Comment: @Oleg Lobachev ist right. It's definitely not a 'geringfügige' research assistant position, but a regular part-time job as 'wissenschaftlicher Mitarbeiter'.

Comment: Hi all, embassy asked me to refer their website for the Research and Internship visa under the National visa category. I think its a work permist Visa. But it is asked for a consent letter from “Bundesagentur für Arbeit”. Could anyone please tell me what this letter is ?

Comment: You need to coordinate with the university administration. They can organize this letter.

Comment: I also want to point out that the (very curious) amount of 19.9 hours per week sounds a lot like the university wants to ensure that you are **not** 50% employed, but <50%. I don't know exactly why, but it's not accurate to say that you have a 50% position (at least not on paper).

Comment: @xLeitix: I don't think so. In Niedersachsen full-time according to TV-L is 39 hours and 48 minutes per week (yes, really), so half is exactly 19.9 hours. See https://www.oeffentlichen-dienst.de/tv-l/arbeitszeit.html

Comment: @PieterNaaijkens Ok, that's weird. I was not aware of this.